# Installing a new table into the Database

Tags: database

So i created a custom module, it's been installed etc, but then i figured out that i need a custom table in my db so i created a `mymodule.install` and in it three hooks (`mymodule_schema(), mymodule_install() and mymodule_uninstall()`).
Now that all works fine if you are installing the module for the first time, or if you uninstall and then install the module again.
But it can be a pain to reinstall a module during development, isn't there a way to trigger the _schema() to install when you want it to ?

Comment: If you don't mind losing the data, you can use drush to reinstall your module. `drush dre mymodule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`drupal_install_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21schema.inc/function/drupal_install_schema/8.4.x) for that:

```
drupal_install_schema('mymodule');
```

If you're looking for somewhere to execute it, a [`hook_update_N()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.4.x) implementation is one potential option.

Comment: Ah thanks, i'll try it later and give some feedback.